# Suggestions for meal-for-two with one lamb shank

Tags: lamb

I have one lamb shank in the freezer. Usually I make tagine with lamb shanks, but I'd need another (for one each) and they're quite pricey. Can anyone suggest what I can do with one left over, to make a [cheap and relatively easy] meal for two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to scale down this recipe, but [Shepard's Pie](http://www.marthastewart.com/854531/lamb-shepherds-pie) or [Lamb Stew](http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/herb_marinated_braised_lamb_shanks/) would be an effective way to share a lamb shank.

Answer (score 2):

Make the tangine.  Take the meat off the bone.  Serve two.

Comment: Do you have a method or recipe that you recommend?